# Which should I use, “pro manko de tempo”, “pro tempomanko”, or “pro tempmanko”?

Tags: word-choice

As far as I understand all three alternatives, *pro manko de tempo*, *pro tempomanko*, and *pro tempmanko*, are correct. However, I wonder if there are any reasons for using one of them rather than the others? Or can I choose freely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of them are correct. In my experience *pro tempomanko* is the most often used form. Probably *tempmanko* is the most uncommon form because of the weird *mpm* combination.

Comment: Thank you! I agree that the _mpm_ combination is a bit weird, so I'll add the o.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose freely, the reasons for the choice will be most likely personal, such as how you first learned it, or how your native language works.

*tempmanko* I think should be limited to the written form, most people (Slavic peakers not included) will have a hard time pronouncing the consonant cluster.

*tempomanko* is just like the German construction *Zeitnot*, Esperanto is very similar to German in the way they allow and build compound words.

*pro manko de tempo* has appeal to speakers of languages that do not compound words as freely, compare with the Romanian *din lipsă de timp*, which is a word-by-word translation.